# Is it okay to leverage useContext when you know the Provider won't be in the component tree for all scenarios

Tags: react-hooks

Wondering if it's okay practice to leverage useContext knowing the Provider won't always be in the component tree. There is a default value set on the Context.

We have a scenario where we'd want to enhance the features of a component if the provider is present and default experience if the provider is not present.

So instead of a hook like the following that throws an error if used outside the provider:

```
import SomeContext from "../context/SomeContext";
const useSomeContext = () => {
  const data = useContext(SomeContext);

  if (!data) {
    throw new Error("useSomeContext must be used within SomeProvider");
  }

  return data;
};
```

We simply return the default value from the context

```
import SomeContext from "../context/SomeContext";
const useSomeContext = () => {
  return useContext(SomeContext);
};
```

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const data = useSomeContext();
  return (
    <>
      {data ? (<div>we can enhance experience</div>) ? (<div>default experience</div>)}
    </>
  );
};
```

The above solution works, just wondering if it is bad practice or if there are some caveats I'm not thinking of knowing that in some scenarios the provider will never be in the component tree and the default context will be returned.